# what does 'y' stand for in apt-get install?

Tags: apt

Could anyone clarify what does the `sudo apt-get install -y <package>` do? what exactly does the -y stand for?

Comment: Needless to say that using the `-y` option imposes the risk of  not getting warnings to prevent something unwanted from happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It stands for yes, so will answer yes to any questions that the `apt-get` command will generate.

You can find out the options of commands by viewing their manual page with the `man` command. In the output of `man apt-get` you can find the following section:

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>
> ```
>        Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>        run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>        changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>        package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
>        abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```

Comment: I beat you to it, Arronical by 25 seconds. The question is a dupe.

Comment: Aaah! Must've been while I was writing! I'll get flagging.